# Can't load .csv file on server in D3.js code

Tags: javascript, csv, heroku, d3.js

So the following code for loading the .csv file is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var final_news_events = [];
  d3.csv("final_news_events.csv", function(data, error) {
    // You're function goes in here.
    console.log("data = ", data);
    final_news_events = data;
  });
</script>
```

I have the above code hosted on github one line 104 in file [new_event_list.html](https://github.com/quinnliu/neweventdetection/blob/master/website/new_event_list.html)

I also pushed this code to heroku and have a live website here: https://neweventdetection.herokuapp.com/

When you open the console for the website it shows `data =  null`

From the line of code `console.log("data = ", data);` in the file new_event_list.html line 108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments in the wrong order in `function(data, error)`.

Swap them and things will work a lot better:

```
  d3.csv("final_news_events.csv", function(error, data) {
```

But keep in mind that the loading is still an asynchronous operation. So instead of assigning the data to a more globally scoped variable (`final_news_events`), do what all the samples for d3 do: act on the data inside the callback function: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV