# How do display array of Objects in D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, heroku, d3.js

So I have a .csv file [final_news_events.csv](https://github.com/quinnliu/neweventdetection/blob/master/website/final_news_events.csv) I want to display the contents of on a website.

The following D3.js code at line 151 of file [new_event_list.html](https://github.com/quinnliu/neweventdetection/blob/master/website/new_event_list.html) isn't working exactly how I want it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  d3.select("body").append("p").text("New paragraph!");
  var final_news_events = [];
  d3.csv("final_news_events.csv")
                            .row(function(d) { return {news_event: d.News_Event}; })
                            .get(function(error, rows) { 
                              console.log(rows); 
                              final_news_events = rows;
                            });
  d3.select("body").append("ol").selectAll("text")
    .data(final_news_events)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
    .text(function(d) {
      return "Object 2";
  });
</script>
```

I've pushed my code to github & heroku so the live heroku website is at
https://neweventdetection.herokuapp.com/

If you open up the console on this website and go to "Elements" in Google chrome you can see that some of the D3.js code is working:

```
<p>New paragraph!</p>
<ol></ol>
```

But how do I make it display:

```
<p>New paragraph!</p>
<ol>
  <li>White House moves to take Cuba off Terrorism List</li>
  <li>US plans stiffer rules protecting retiree cash</li>
  <li>Rival Factions in Ukraine Are Urged to Withdraw Heavy Weapons</li>
  <li>Boko Haram Abducted Nigerian Girls One Year Ago</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It seems to me you are using d3 library incorrectly. Check https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv. According to this article you should work with loaded data only in callback function. In your example you work with unloaded data. I suggest you to move the last piece of code (the one that starts with d3.select('body'...) to callback function in get method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like Frank explained in the second half of his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654605/cant-load-csv-file-on-server-in-d3-js-code/29656352#29656352):

Data loading is asynchronous, so this code:

```
d3.select("body").append("ol").selectAll("text")
  .data(final_news_events)
  .enter()
  .append("li")
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Object 2";
});
```

runs BEFORE the file is loaded, at which point `final_news_events` is still `[]` and nothing gets appended to the DOM.

If you wrap that code in a render function:

```
function renderList(newsEvents) {
  d3.select("body").append("ol").selectAll("text")
    .data(newsEvents)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
    .text(function(d) {
      return "Object 2";
  });
}
```

then you can call that function when the data is loaded — from here:

```
.get(function(error, rows) { 
  console.log(rows); 
  renderList(rows);
});
```

And so you won't even need to set the "global" `final_news_events`.